# OffsetDateTime does not parse correctly the time when sending a defined time

Tags: java, spring-boot, time, offsetdatetime, datetimeparseexception

OffsetDateTime does not correctly parse the time when a defined time is sent to me

I have a service with a timezone UTC +4:00

I am sent two possible cases in STRING:

```
1- 2022-03-30T11:22:33.44+04:00 
2- 2022-03-30T11:22:33.44+0400
```

but when I do a

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS[xxx][xx][X]");

OffsetDateTime.parse("2022-03-30T11:22:33.44+04:00", formatter);
```

always returns me **2022-03-30T11:22:33.440**

This is technically incorrect because my servers are in the same zone, so it should be: **2022-03-30T07:22:22:33.44Z**

but whatever parse I do it doesn't work, is there any way to do it this way?

Comment: From your code I am getting `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-03-30T11:22:33.44+04:00' could not be parsed at index 20`.

Comment: *always returns me **2022-03-30T11:22:33.440*** Are you saying it returns an `OffsatDateTime` without offset??!! That sounds extremely strange.

Comment: That is my doubt, it returns without the offset and but it does not apply it, I should remove those hours +04:00 and apply it to the code.

Comment: This works for me: (1) Defining `formatter` as `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).appendPattern("[xxx][xx][X]").toFormatter()`. (2) Parsing this way: `OffsetDateTime.parse(input, formatter).withOffsetSameLocal(ZoneOffset.UTC)`. From both your input strings I get `2022-03-30T11:22:33.440Z`.

Comment: Hi @OleV.V. At that point I've arrived too, but the thing is that where my jar is hosted the JVM has UTC +04:00

if it is sent 2022-03-30T11:22:33.44+04:00 being in the same zone it should calculate correctly that timezone and disconnect the 4h that are sent to the string that is to say:

2022-03-30T07:22:22:33.44Z

Comment: *so it should be: **2022-03-30T07:22:22:33.44Z*** Not according to the docs. It should preserve the offset from the string, so `+04:00`.

Comment: To use the JVM’s default time zone regardless of what is in the string, parse like `OffsetDateTime.parse(input, formatter).atZoneSimilarLocal(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toOffsetDateTime()`.

Comment: Correct, and when I debug it is taking the zone correctly, but it does not take away the 4 hours, it is still 11:22.... instead of 07:22. I can not find a parse correctly, because it removes the +04:00 but does not apply it to the date only removes that string.

Comment: Ah, that’s what you wanted? Use `atZoneSameInstant()`. So `OffsetDateTime.parse(input, formatter).atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toOffsetDateTime()`